Visual Studio can't connect to MacOS Sequoia
I have just updated my iMac to Sequoia and consequently Xcode to the new version that also contains iOS 18.
After this update, neither Visual Studio for Mac nor Visual Studio on Windows can't see the list of iOS simulators.

There is no update for Visual Studio; Visual Studio Code is not working for MAUI as usual. With Visual Studio for Mac I can run the application for macOS and Android but not for iOS (and the Generic Simulator doesn't do anything.
From Visual Studio, when I try to connect my iMac, I get a different error.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


I opened Xcode and agreed on all the licences. It is getting difficult and difficult to work with MAUI...
Update
Today, Microsoft released the Visual Studio 17.11.4. This version can connect to the iMac but I can't see the list of simulators for iOS.
Do you have to update anything in the iMac?

VS/Mac has been retired so that's never going to work

@stuartd I know but it is still more efficient than VS for iOS

Generally support for new versions of Apple's OS and XCode are not available immediately.  It's generally not a good idea to update XCode until you know a supported version of the Microsoft tools are available.

@Enrico I was very angry when they cancelled VS/Mac. But there is no way a retired product will get updated for a new version of macOS.

The release notes for VS2022 17.11.4 which has just come out say "Fixed ArgumentNullException iOS remote build error when switching between different SDK versions" - might be worth a try with that?

@stuartd doing it now...

After the installation of VS 17.11.4, the error above disappeared but I can't see the list of simulators for iOS

if you have the following system environment, there is a workaround:

macOS Sequoia
Xcode 16.0
Visual Studio V 17.11.4

Then you just need to install the Xcode beta version 16.0 from June
(Simulator 16.0 - 1033) and the coresponding command line tool (16A5171c)
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20802#issuecomment-2356393897

Do I have to remove the other Xcode? There is an update for Xcode 16.1: is it OK?

I don't remove the Xcode, you can switch between the version -> Xcode->location.

I have just created this post with all the steps https://puresourcecode.com/dotnet/maui/sequoia-doesnt-work-with-maui/

There is a fix now, strangely not very easy to find:
Update the workload to version 8.0.402.1.
Works fine with XCode 16.
See: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/releases/tag/dotnet-8.0.1xx-xcode16.0-8303
